# embedded newlib-nano printf causes hardfault

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, cortex-m, newlib

I compile the "same" code on 2 targets (one Freescale, one STM32 both with cortex M4). I use `--specs=nano.specs` and I have implemented the `_write` function as an empty function and this causes the whole `printf` to be optimized away by GCC's `-Wno-unused-function` even with `-O0` on the STM32 target (seen in map). This is fine and I would like to reproduce that on Freescale target.

But on the Freescale target (with same compile flags) the printf causes hardfault. But if I go step by step with the debugger (assembly stepping) the `printf` goes through the library without hardfaulting. Simple breakpoint breakpoint sometimes not hit and run from any location in `printf` causes hardfault too (so it is unlikely that it is a peripheral issue).

So far I checked that stack and heap are not overlapping and some other far-fetched disassembly.

Why isn't the printf optimized away on freescale target ?
What can cause the library code to hardfault ?
Why is it OK when doing assembly step by step debug ?

EDIT:

- Using arm-none-eabi-gcc 5.4.1 for both MCU with same libraries.
- I do not want to remove printf, this is only a first step to be able to use
  them or not.
- Vector table has default weak vectors for all ISR so it should be OK
- Using the [register dump](https://blog.feabhas.com/2013/02/developing-a-generic-hard-fault-handler-for-arm-cortex-m3cortex-m4/) it seems that the faulty instruction is at address 4 (reset vector) so the new question is now: why does the chip reset ?

Comment: problem is 100% somewhere else.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 this is exactly why I need to solve it because I don't know what could happen somewhere else. Could your comment be more usefull ?

Comment: Unfortunately DH are quite difficult to diagnose without the actual software and hardware. I afraid it is not possible remotely. Using my crystal ball - I bet problems with the vector table - not initialised properly or some vectors defaulted to DH. When you step with the debugger interrupt is not triggered. When you run program "the normal" way it triggers. Maybe timer, maybe systick, maybe something else. You hav different startups for both tragets - need to take a look yourself. I know what I write. If is 100% somewhere else.

Comment: If all you want to do is to remove the printf, why not just define an empty function?

Comment: Are you compiling both with the same compiler instance? Same libraries? Which gcc version is that?

Comment: Which toolchains are you using, more exactly?

Comment: Oh btw, this could perhaps be caused by a missing ISR in the interrupt vector table. Are you sure the vector table is ok even after porting the code?

Answer (score 0):

When ARM applications seem to work properly until `printf` is used, the most common problem is stack misalignment. Put a breakpoint at the entry point of the function that calls `printf` and inspect the stack pointer. If the pointer isn't double-word aligned, you've found your problem.

Comment: stack pointer is aligned : 0x1fff18e0 before printf and  0x1fff1830 in hardfault. 
And linker script is correct `. = ALIGN(4);`

Comment: @Julien That's not your problem then, but it would typically be `ALIGN(8);` to ensure the stack is on a double-word boundary.

Comment: @D Krueger, just for my comprehension, why align(8) ? isn't a DWORD 4 bytes ?

Comment: @Julien Cortex has 4-byte words, so a double-word is 8 bytes.

Comment: @Julien Also, don't check at the call to `printf`, but at entry to the function that calls `printf`. The code that pushes the arguments to a variadic function may leave the stack double-word aligned even if it wasn't previously.

Comment: @D Krueger thanks for the explication. I modified the linker script to align on DWORD and checked stack alignment a various points. Problem is not from there.

Answer (score 0):

The common reason for crashing in printf with newlib is incorrectly set up free storage, especially if you are using an RTOS (ie FreeRTOS). Since 2019 NXP (formerly Freescale) includes my solution in MCUXpresso. You can find code and detailed explanation here: https://github.com/DRNadler/FreeRTOS_helpers